# What is $(\sqrt3-1)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, radicals

Does $(\sqrt3-1)^2=3+1$  or $3-2\sqrt3+1$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Remember that $$\begin{align} \color{red}{(a+b)^2}&=(a+b)(a+b) \\
&=a(a+b)+b(a+b)\\
&=a^2+ab+ba+b^2 \\
&=\color{red}{a^2+2ab+b^2}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that: $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2,(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$

Let $a=3^{1/2}$ and let $b=1$ in both sides of the above result, we get:

$(3^{1/2}-1)^2=(3^{1/2})^2-2(3^{1/2})(1)+(1)^2=3-2(3^{1/2})+1=4-2(3^{1/2})=4-2\sqrt{3}=2(2-\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Use `$$\begin{align} A&=B \\ &=C \\ &=D.\end{align}$$` for $$\begin{align} A&=B \\ &=C \\ &=D.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(\sqrt 3 -1 )^2 = (\sqrt 3)^2 + 1^2 - 2 \cdot 1 \cdot \sqrt 3 = 4-2\sqrt 3$ , by applying $$(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ab$$

Answer (score -1):

It is equal to $3 - 2 \sqrt{3} +1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.